# Como posicionar elementos en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy creando un dashboard con la plantilla de adminlte y no logro obtener el resultado que espero, mi pagina se muestra de la siguiente forma. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se vea la pantalla completa, es decir que ocupe todo el ancho de la pagina, pero por alguna razon no logro obtener el resultado. (Los cuadrados rojos, indican el espacio que deseo eliminar)

Adjunto un pastebin del codigo: https://pastebin.com/9ahPBDhn

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: La plantilla ya viene a pantalla completa quizás algo has implementado mal y la has arruinado.

Answer (score -1):

Por defecto AdminLTE es exactamente como quieres que sea, parece algún tipo de problemas con la clase predeterminada de Bootstrap container puede ser que en el código sin darte cuenta tengas class="container" en lugar de class="container-fluid"

lo otro que me parece raro son las clases que tienes en tu  eliminalas y prueba haber si funciona a toda la pantalla.